# Owl Carousel Auto Width with margin not working

Tags: css, owl-carousel

I have a fixed height on all my images and need to keep the image in proportion as the screen width gets smaller.

```
#owl-demo .item img {
  display: block;
  width: auto;
  height: 300px
}
```

This works fine until I need to put a margin in between the images.

```
#owl-demo .item {
   margin:0 10px 0 10px;
}
```

The margin won't show and the images are side by side still. The `margin` will show if I put `width: 100%`

```
#owl-demo .item img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px
}
```

But then the image is no longer in proportion.

I tried with Owl's own demo and this is the case. If you inspect one of the images and change it to the code at the top with `width: auto` you will see the margin no longer works. You will need to remove the `max-width: 100%` from the `img` tag from bootstrap also.

http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/images.html

[image]

Comment: If I understand you correctly, it sounds like you need to just change the image height to a max-height or min-height, but I don't completely understand what your end goal is. I understand you want to maintain image proportions, but is your goal to keep the same amount of items inside your carousel too? Otherwise, if your width varies then your height must vary too. Another option could be that you have a fixed height on your image containers but not the images, then just 'overflow:hidden' on your containers.

Comment: Sorry the end goal is to have margins in between the items/images. The goal is not to keep the same amount of images within the carousel, I am using the responsive feature also. As the screen width decreases the images will be cut off slightly (like the example screenshot above and stay in proportion) until it reaches a particular break point and decrease the amount of images.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you're using version 1.3.X

Try upgrading to version 2 and you'll be fine.